# How to use find function to find a specific coordinate?

Tags: matlab

For Matlab, I've been given a function `y= 3x+4`
I need to find the x value when `y = 25000` using the 'find' function.
I've tried `x = find(y == 25000)` and receive nothing. I know the function returns index of nonzero values. But not sure how to use it in this context.

Answer (score 3):

This would typically require `solve`, as you are trying to solve an equation.

Unless you already had a vector with the correct value, in that case you could use `find` like so:

```
x = 0:25000
y = 3*x+4

x(find(y==25000))
```

Make sure to check `doc find` and `doc solve` to understand what they both do.

Comment: Oh Thanks! I shall look into the solve function. In regards to your coding for the find function, I tried it and it returned [] which I assume is nothing. I forgot to mention that I have a linspace function from 0 to 0.1 for x, does this affect it?

Comment: @user3509716 If you want it for floating point numbers, or inexact matches, you may want to try something like: `max(x(y<=25000))` --- In case `y` is not monotonic you can also google for the `ismemberf` file exchange submission.

Comment: @user3509716 Well, if `x` goes from `0` to `0.1`, then `y` is going to go from `4` to `4.3`, so you haven't got a chance in hell of finding `25000`.

Comment: oh sorry, to clarify i was using y=3x+4 as an example equation since the equation im using is much larger.

Comment: Since you stated that your use case uses a much larger equation, better be careful when comparing floats with == operator though.

Answer (score 1):

You should look for the best match instead of an exact result:

```
x = 0:0.1:50000;
y = 3*x+4;
[value,index] = min(abs(y-25000))
x(index)
y(index)
```